# Getting SDL2 to work on Clion, Windows 10 using MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sdl-2, clion

I cannot for the life of me get SDL2 to work with my programming group's project.

I'm using

-Clion 1.2.1

-SDL 2.0.3

-MinGW 5.0

The compiler starts yelling at me from within the Graphics.h file which includes SDL like so:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
```

with the error being:

```
fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I tried including with

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

which still yielded the same error.

I downloaded SDL from the MinGW 32/64-bit download of development libraries from: https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php. I also linked the respective ..\SDL2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include and lib to path in system->advanced system settings->...

Still nothing.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(ClionProjects)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lsdl2")

set(SOURCE_FILES
        Kod/Graphics/Graphics.cc
        Kod/Graphics/Graphics.h
        Kod/Game/Game.cc
        Kod/Game/Game.h
        Kod/Gameboard/Gameboard.cc
        Kod/Gameboard/Gameboard.h
        Kod/Meeple/Meeple.cc
        Kod/Meeple/Meeple.h
        Kod/Player/Player.cc
        Kod/Player/Player.h
        Kod/Resource/Resource.cc
        Kod/Resource/Resource.h
        Kod/Tile/Tile.cc
        Kod/Tile/Tile.h
        Kod/Carcassonne.cc)


add_executable(ClionProjects ${SOURCE_FILES} Kod/Carcassonne.cc)
target_link_libraries(ClionProjects SDL2main SDL2 SDL2_image)
```

is the cmakefile I have in Clion. I've been bashing my head bloody trying to get this to work and none of the previous Stackoverflow questions managed to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I uses [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) in my project. The MINGW64 vesion of SDL2 and the other library were installed, as well as the other toolchains like gcc, cmake, and pkg-config (toolchains are MINGW64 version as well).

Then I point my CLion toolchain configuration to the `c:\msys2\mingw64`, given that I install the msys2 at `c:\msys2`.

The FindPkgConfig CMake module is used to locate the SDL2 library and include files location.

Please find the example below (I also use FreeType2 and harfbuzz as well). The important part is the FindPkgConfig part (pkg_check_modules) and include/link part.

Make sure to reload the configuration after you have modified the cmake file.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (pgengine)
# The version number.
set (Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set (Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR 1)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)
aux_source_directory(src SRC_LIST)
aux_source_directory(src/game SRC_LIST)
aux_source_directory(src/graphics SRC_LIST)
aux_source_directory(src/sound SRC_LIST)
aux_source_directory(src/system SRC_LIST)
aux_source_directory(src/visual_novel SRC_LIST)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)

pkg_check_modules(FREETYPE2 REQUIRED freetype2)
pkg_check_modules(HARFBUZZ REQUIRED harfbuzz)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_IMAGE REQUIRED SDL2_image)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_MIXER REQUIRED SDL2_mixer)


include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${FREETYPE2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${HARFBUZZ_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories (${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS}
                  ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARY_DIRS}
                  ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARY_DIRS}
                  ${FREETYPE2_LIBRARY_DIRS}
                  ${HARFBUZZ_LIBRARY_DIRS})

target_link_libraries (pgengine ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
                                ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
                                ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARIES}
                                ${FREETYPE2_LIBRARIES}
                                ${HARFBUZZ_LIBRARIES})
```

This has been tested on Windows (MSYS2) and Linux.

Comment: I managed to get SDL and SDL_image to work (not using msys2 however, not sure how to, to be honest). I have another issue now that you might be able to help with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226818/undefined-reference-to-ft-load-glyph-and-other-sdl2-ttf-functions-using-cmak?noredirect=1#comment56208028_34226818