# "undefined reference to `FT_Load_Glyph'" and other SDL2_ttf functions using CMAKE

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, mingw, sdl-2

Using this CMAKE-file in Clion on Windows 10 (using MinGW 5.0):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(ClionProjects)

# configure the SDL (cf. "SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\pkgconfig\sdl2.pc")
# C++ flags
set(SDL2_Flags "-mwindows -Wl,--no-undefined -static-libgcc")
# library paths
set(SDL2_ROOT     "C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32")
set(SDL2_Includes "${SDL2_ROOT}/include")
set(SDL2_LibDir   "${SDL2_ROOT}/lib")
# imported targets for CMake (cf. https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets)
add_library(SDL2     STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library(SDL2main STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library(SDL2_image STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library(SDL2_ttf STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET SDL2     PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SDL2_LibDir}/libSDL2.a")
set_property(TARGET SDL2main PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SDL2_LibDir}/libSDL2main.a")
set_property(TARGET SDL2_image PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SDL2_LibDir}/libSDL2_image.a")
set_property(TARGET SDL2_ttf PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SDL2_LibDir}/libSDL2_ttf.a")
# the libs to link against
# note: as always with gcc, the order is important...
set(SDL2_Libs mingw32 SDL2 SDL2main m SDL2_image SDL2_ttf dinput8 dxguid dxerr8 user32 gdi32 winmm imm32 ole32 oleaut32 shell32 version uuid)

# configure the project
# include the SDL flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 ${SDL2_Flags}")
# collect the sources
set(SOURCE_FILES
        Kod/Graphics/Graphics.cc
        Kod/Graphics/Graphics.h
        Kod/Game/Game.cc
        Kod/Game/Game.h
        Kod/Gameboard/Gameboard.cc
        Kod/Gameboard/Gameboard.h
        Kod/Meeple/Meeple.cc
        Kod/Meeple/Meeple.h
        Kod/Player/Player.cc
        Kod/Player/Player.h
        Kod/Resource/Resource.cc
        Kod/Resource/Resource.h
        Kod/Tile/Tile.cc
        Kod/Tile/Tile.h
        Kod/Carcassonne.cc)
# define the target
add_executable(ClionProjects ${SOURCE_FILES} Kod/Carcassonne.cc)
# include the SDL headers
target_include_directories(ClionProjects SYSTEM PRIVATE ${SDL2_Includes})
# link against the SDL (and its dependencies)
target_link_libraries(ClionProjects ${SDL2_Libs})


#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lSDL2 -lSDL2-image")


#add_executable(ClionProjects ${SOURCE_FILES} Kod/Carcassonne.cc)
#target_link_libraries(ClionProjects SDL2main SDL2 SDL2_image)
```

I get this error:

```
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `Load_Glyph':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:609: undefined reference to `FT_Load_Glyph'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:671: undefined reference to `FT_Outline_Transform'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:677: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Glyph'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:678: undefined reference to `FT_Stroker_New'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:694: undefined reference to `FT_Render_Glyph'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:895: undefined reference to `FT_Done_Glyph'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:607: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Char_Index'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:682: undefined reference to `FT_Stroker_Set'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:683: undefined reference to `FT_Glyph_Stroke'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:684: undefined reference to `FT_Stroker_Done'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:686: undefined reference to `FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:688: undefined reference to `FT_Done_Glyph'
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `TTF_Init':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:340: undefined reference to `FT_Init_FreeType'
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `TTF_CloseFont':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:927: undefined reference to `FT_Done_Face'
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `TTF_OpenFontIndexRW':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:432: undefined reference to `FT_Open_Face'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:460: undefined reference to `FT_Set_Char_Size'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:454: undefined reference to `FT_Set_Charmap'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:484: undefined reference to `FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes'
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `TTF_SizeUTF8':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:1241: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Kerning'
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:1429: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Kerning'
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `TTF_RenderUTF8_Shaded':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:1610: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Kerning'
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:1780: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Kerning'
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended_Wrapped':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:2048: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Kerning'
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `TTF_Quit':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:2196: undefined reference to `FT_Done_FreeType'
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `TTF_GetFontKerningSize':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:2209: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Kerning'
C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2_ttf.a(SDL_ttf.o): In function `TTF_GlyphIsProvided':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL_ttf/SDL2_ttf-2.0.12-source/foo-x86/../SDL_ttf.c:1138: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Char_Index'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\ClionProjects.dir\build.make:289: recipe for target 'ClionProjects.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [ClionProjects.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ClionProjects.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ClionProjects.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ClionProjects.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ClionProjects.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [ClionProjects] Error 2
makefile:117: recipe for target 'ClionProjects' failed
```

I have added SDL2_ttf.dll to system32 and the folder where the executable will be, added SDL2_ttf.h to /include where all the other .h-files for SDL2 is and also added libSDL2_ttf.a to /lib. I don't understand why I would get those errors... I there a problem with the order of my flags?

Comment: Googling for names of undefined symbols reveals, that they are defined in `TrueType` library. I don't see anything, which looks like this library, in your link list. BTW, the common way to link with 3d-party library, like `SDL2`, is to use `find_package(STDL2)`. There are a lot of tutorials in net about using this command within simple project.

Comment: I've tried getting find_package(SDL2) to work, but to no avail. Then I found the answer marked correct in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857351/linking-sdl2-and-clion which this is essentially a copy-paste of. My project partners compile it in a *nix enviroment and only use the -lsdl -lsdl_image -lsdl_ttf flags, no TrueType library =S.

Comment: *nix envoronment differs from MinGW one. (And even environments on different Linux disros may differ). That is why hardcoding libraries' names is not good for portable projects.

Comment: But isn't SDL_tff the TrueType library? the cmakefile is mine alone so nothing is hardcoded.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed FreeType now, but I am unsure of what library to include to access it. the only .a file is libfreetype.dll.a, is that the one?

Comment: `SDL_tff` seems to be **SDL-related** functions for `tff`, so it is not equal to `tff`. As for FreeType, you can use [find_package(FreeType)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindFreetype.html) for linking with it.

Comment: `FT_*` functions are from freetype2 library. You could add the `-lfreetype` linker flag.

Comment: Also if you don't have the freetype installed, try copy the libfreetype.a into the `/lib` or `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib` (I'm not sure which one is the correct. Been a long time since I used MINGW.). Add the linker flag and then rebuild again.

I'd suggest you to try MSYS2 though, much easier to work with. I can write a tutorial if you want me to :-).

Comment: would love a tutorial! I'm quite new to cmake files and c++ development in general so it's all still a bit unintuitive to me.

Comment: As in depth as you have the energy for =P. I'm quite unsure if I've 'installed' the libraries properly as well,  so any tutorial-esque help for that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is how I work with SDL2, SDL2_ttf, SDL2_mixer, etc. with CLion. This is quite different approache than what you've been doing so far, so please keep that in mind. I'll be using MSYS2 for the POSIX-like environment (instead of MINGW/MSys you are using).

First of, I would start with installing MSYS2. Grab it from http://msys2.github.io/ . Then, depends on the version you have installed, you will get 2 or 3 shortcuts in the start menu.

From now on I'd stick with `MINGW-W64-x86_64` version of the toolchain. If you are using the `i686` one, replace `x86_64` with `i686` (and `mingw64` with `mingw32`).

Open the `MinGW-w64 Win64 shell` shortcut from the start menu. You will be welcome with a bash shell. At this point I'd start with installing the toolchain first. At the prompt, input the below command

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-make mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
```

The package manager will then install gcc, cmake, pkg-config, make and gdb for you. This includes all of the dependencies of these tool, so it would take quite a bit.

Then install the libraries by calling below commands at the prompt.:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2 mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_ttf mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_mixer mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_image
```

pacman (package manager) will download and install these 3 libraries, along with their dependencies.

The steps above is on top of my head. I haven't retested it yet (as I already have working environment). If you run into problems let me know. I might retest it later. Also the step above is applicable for the Arch Linux users too, just replace the package name and you'll be good.

Next up, open the CLion. Go to **File->Settings**. Choose **toolchains** under **Build, Execution, and Deployment**. Then change the MinGW home to the mingw64 under your MSYS2 installation path.

[image: CLion Settings]

Then everything should be ready.

I will use the `FindPkgConfig` module to get the linker flags and include flags of each library I use. This module replies on pkg-config command we've installed earlier. In `CMakeList.txt`, add the following line :

```
INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)

pkg_check_modules(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_IMG REQUIRED SDL2_image)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_TTF REQUIRED SDL2_ttf)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_MIX REQUIRED SDL2_mixer)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_IMG_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_MIX_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories (${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_IMG_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_MIX_LIBRARY_DIRS})

target_link_libraries (TestSDL2
    ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2_IMG_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2_MIX_LIBRARIES})
```

Change the TestSDL2 to your executable. You probably have to remove the existing FindSDL or any commands that looks for SDL libraries.

This approach is much cleaner than the custom module. The downside is it is pretty much tied to the system's libraries file (especially if you are using Linux). Also if you have to package the exe file, you will have to look for the dll files inside the MSYS2/mingw64/bin manually (it's not very difficult by the way).

Another possible approach is to include the SDL as subproject. I haven't done this before so I cannot explain.

I think after you're familliar with how this work, you can applies the same approaches to other libraries as well (box2d, for example). You can see the list of available packages at https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages , the package names have to be modified a little bit by insterting the arch name just before the library names (eg. `mingw-w64-x86_64-box2d` for `mingw-w64-box2d` package).

Comment: Thank you so much for the tutorial! The installation went very smoothly but I'm now getting a "undefined reference to `SDL_main'" error. I know it's much to ask, but do you think you could give even more assistance with the makefile? the external librarier that I need are SDL2, SDL2_image, SDL2_ttf and freetype. I tried using pkg_check_modules(FREETYPE REQUIRED freetype2) but that yielded strange errors further down: "  Syntax error in cmake code at

    C:/Users/~/ClionProjects/CMakeLists.txt:15

  when parsing string

    ${freetype"

Comment: The "undefined reference to `SDL_main` usually caused by the missing of `int main(char**, int)`. If you use a different signature of `main` then please try readjust the signature.

Comment: And if you don't use the FreeType directly, you don't have to call `pkg_check_modules(FREETYPE REQUIRED freetype2)`. I was doing this because I don't use SDL2_ttf (I do my own text rendering).

Comment: duh, I should've realized that was the error! It compiles beautifully now but when I try to run it (which works perfectly on Linux) I get this error: Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)" without the program even opening a window. Setting a breakpoint even at the first line of the main(int argc, char* argv) and debugging it just exits, any ideas? googling a bit it seems like an "access violation" error, but I don't even know how to start fixing it. =(

Comment: Well the reason it was working perfectly on Linux because, in Linux main is the actual main function of your program. The main function of the console can be in any definition AFAIK. In Windows, in the other hand, main get renamed to `SDL_main` and will be called by `WinMain()` so if the signature mismatched then the compile would fail to recognize your main function.

Comment: yeah, I've run into that one before :) do you have any idea about the error?

Comment: About the error code... this is a difficult bit. It would be nice if I can remote to your machine and see how was the settings :-). Regardless please try checking the Configuration, especially the **working directory**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99408/discussion-between-tenbin-and-wutipong-wongsakuldej).

Comment: Sorry been too busy around the new year. Are you able to get things working now ?

Comment: I've been busy with exams as well so I haven't been able to get it working yet, sadly.

Comment: regarding the "access violation", if you don't mind, you can pass me the code and I'll try to figure out what goes wrong.

My best guess is in the constructors and the static variable though.

Comment: Sure, https://www.dropbox.com/sh/48bz5bqalf370js/AADu0iQUlzsICd44QVqcoZ-da?dl=0 is a link to an archive with the code, leave a comment when you've downloaded it =)

Comment: Just tried the code. I see 2 problems... 1. Menu.png is missing. 2. All resource files are referred with .., which assumed that the working directory is a direct subdirectory of your project directory. Try adjust the working directory (inside Run/Debug Configurations). I've actually get it working though, btw :-).

Comment: Oh god! Thank you so much! It finally works on Windows! Legend!

Comment: It seems to render the tiles a few pixels too low compared to how it should (and does on Linux), do you have any idea what might cause that? the background image also looks a bit wonky compared to how it should, seems it's shrunk the image a bit, causing some weird missing pixels.